# How to model an object with width and depth, based only on an image that shows the outline?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

[image]

I am able to layout the shape using vertex extrusion but not able to give like width to it.

[image]

Comment: if it's flat you can just extrude the shape you've drawn

Comment: U mean extrude using median point or individual origins??

Comment: I have added picture of what i have done , as u see i want it to have depth like in the original image (inward or something like that)

Comment: oh ok I misunderstood what you meant, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Ok gimme a minute

Comment: Its taking so long to process , I am new to it so don't really know how all this work

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=P7rqmmkL" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/P7rqmmkL/)

Comment: I have added can u plz check

Comment: Yes, I'm going to answer  ;)

Comment: Thank You Brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it done, just want to thank you for helping.However I used a slightly different workflow than you suggested.I was not much familiar to Illustrator so i could not track the image properly as suggested by one of you, So i did it in blender, I used a plane and traced the whole image in wireframe mode just by extruding and adding loopcuts when needed(Mirror Modifier On), and used subdivision at the end and it turned out pretty fine.Hope this help any other user having the same problem.Thank You

[image]

Comment: Be sure to apply all the modifiers and then extrude it backwards for some depth.

Answer (score 6):

Trace the shape as path in a vectorial drawing program like illustrator or Inkscape

[image]
and save as SVG.

Then import the svg file into blender.

For a filled shape set the curve to be a 2D curve and filled to "both"

[image]

Give the curve some extrusion.

[image]

Form there on you can convert the curve to mesh for further editing.

Comment: Wow Thank You So Much Brother

Answer (score 5):

I thought it would be easily fixable but your shape is a bit more complexe than I thought. If I had to do it from scratch, I would follow the shape with some extrusions, like this:

[image]

If you want to start from your current mesh, delete the extrusion to only keep the edges, don't forget to remove doubles, give some extrusions to the remaining edges, like this:

[image]
[image]

Etc... then extrude to give it thickness and give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to smooth it.

[image]

You could also convert your edges to curves, and give it thickness, but it will also need rework.

Comment: Thanks For Putting In the time brother, really appreciate it.
However, i already tried what you are saying but it look very jagged and i want it smooth, I also tried subdivision after following the shape through extrusion but it doesn't satisfy me that much.
Anyways Thanks Again

Comment: I'm not sure why it looked jagged as you say, once you give it Subsurf it should get rounder