# Extrude from PNG or SVG?

Tags: image, import, edges, extrude

I'm very new to this.
I need to create objects which seem to have solidity from imported images.
I'm cutting out in Photoshop some original artwork and from these I'm trying to make them seem 'thick'.
I though that exporting as PNG and importing would work but extruding just creates another plane with air in-between. What I want is that the edge of the extruded object keeps the colours of the front/back. I tried doing a convert to mesh, same result.
I think that I can create a 'solid' edge by making an SVG in photoshop from a path and extruding that, then sandwiching the front, middle and back together but I'm sure there's an easy way to do it. any guidance is very much appreciated!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84129/is-there-a-way-to-add-fake-thickness-to-an-alpha-image-texture  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40997/how-can-i-make-a-hexagonal-grill/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/tracing-a-monochrome-image-into-a-3d-extruded-object-with-a-script/1610#1610

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183131/how-to-model-an-object-with-width-and-depth-based-only-on-an-image-that-shows-t