# making a Silhouette image into a 3D model

Tags: mesh

I am very new to Blender so I fully expect to be told... function xyz does exactly this, unfortunately the Blender manual rabbit-hole is so deep that if I jump down it I am unlikely to find my way out of it again. Basicly what I want to do is use a .png image of a silhouette, (for instance a heart shape) and create a 3d image, (as if the silhouette had been cut from a plank of wood). as I said I am pretty sure this is comparatively easy but I have no idea where to start looking. Many thanks for any help pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Am I right in interpreting this as you wanting to do the Blender equivalent of simply drawing an outline on e.g. a piece of wood then cutting that wood along that outline? Or are you trying to take e.g. an image of a face and turning it into a 3D model of that face? Both would be doable with some manual labour, but the former is comparatively simple and the latter quite a bit more complex.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183131/how-to-model-an-object-with-width-and-depth-based-only-on-an-image-that-shows-t https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52563/how-do-i-turn-my-png-image-into-a-mesh-object